# How can i turn on the speakerphone

Tags: iphone

I need to make a call from the app. But i need to activate the speakerphone mode. How can i turn on the speakerphone by code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can't turn do much more than to have the iPhone launch the phone app and dial a number.  You have no control over the sound output after that.